# Directory.Exists() always returning false?

Tags: c#

I am experiencing a strange problem at the moment with my C# code. I am attempting to use the folderBrowserDialog to retrieve the path of a folder selected by the user.

Once the user clicks a button to confirm the selection (the chosen path of which appears in "textBox1"), if the folder location is found, should return the message "connection established" (if the directory/file found) or "no connection found" (if the file/directory does not exist).

For some odd reason however, the code *always* seem to return false when checking if the directory exists - and yes, it does exist. My application requests admin rights in it's manifest file as I thought this would solve the problem, so I'm still stumped on this one.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //BROWSE 
  folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
  textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var path = textBox1.Text + @"\" + "connection.pss";
  //ESTABLISH CONNECTION

  if (textBox1.TextLength > 0)
  {
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    { 
      connectionstatus.Text = "CONNECTION ESTABLISHED!";
      //SET UP VARIABLES
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
      connectionstatus.Text = "NO CONNECTION FOUND!";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW: you might want to consider using [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than concatenating strings to build up paths to files / folders. It's less error prone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That directory doesn't exist. That file exists. :)

Use `File.Exists` instead.

Comment: No problem, @Kya. It just takes another eye sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Connection.pss is not part of the directory.  Try either just checking the directory or use File.Exists()